# Full featured session manager for (any) tiling window manager

Tags: window-manager, software-rec, session

looking for a full featured session manager that would store running programs with their running context and their window position.

### Short version

In short, I am looking for a functionality that would behave like a hibernation of multiple users' sessions, with high-level API.

### Long version

I realized that the ideal way how I would like to use a computer is the following:

1. Turn it on, log in.
2. Type in what I would like to do, for example: 'browse internet', 'university homework', 'job', ...etc.
3. Some launcher would load up the configuration of the selected session and restore everything just the way it was last time when I used the session.
4. Maybe sometimes I would like to switch the session on the fly.
5. Save sessions and log off.

After some searching I came to a realization that this type of launcher and session store is hard to come by. This is, I think, mainly due to the fact that serializing the running context of each program is highly dependent on that program and therefore having a launcher that works for every program is nearly impossible. For example for terminals one would have to remember the command ran, the state of the program launched by the command and the CWD. For browsers it would be only the tabs opened.

For terminal, I use tmux session. It works quite well, but I would rather avoid using tmux, if it weren't for this one feature.
I am using i3, so naturally I tried searching for some i3 session manager. The one I found only restored the programs (not their running contexts), and tried to position them as they were (unsuccessfully).

I imagine that this functionality is dreamed of by many, yet I haven't found the 'perfect' solution.

So here I am, asking you.
Do you know of any program that would fulfill my expectations?
Do you think that what I am describing is possible? If so, how, in your opinion, would one go about storing running context of a program?

Thanks for all the answers.